# What is internal PSD format for no max compatibility?

Tags: photoshop, file-format

I saved a Photoshop file without maximum compatibility. I thought this would result in a file with all internal Photoshop sections intact except that there would be no fifth section (the Image Data section), figuring the Layer and Mask Info section would terminate the file.

Well I do see (A) the 26-byte header, (B) the zero-length Color Mode Data, and (C) the Image Resources section - all this as expected. But the 4-byte length at the beginning of the Image Resources section takes me to an area which I would expect to be the beginning of the Layer and Mask Info section, but instead I seem to be still in the middle of what appears to be Image Resource data. The file opens just fine so it’s not a matter of corruption.

So my question is, can anyone explain exactly what it means internally for a .PSD file to be saved with maximum compatibility turned off? I ask because having it turned on is required for our operation, we have 795 files in hand to check and countless thousands more ongoing, and we don’t want to open each and every one in Photoshop to check it. If we know what to look for I can just do a quick server-based internal check.

Plus, I just want to know.

Comment: @PascalCuoq Thanks for the edit - didn't see that tag available.

Answer (score 0):

I believe documents saved with *maximised compatibility* have a *Thumbnail Resource Format* as described in the correspondingly named section of this document...

[link](http://www.adobe.com/devnet-apps/photoshop/fileformatashtml/)

Comment: Thanks Mark, but the file I'm analyzing saved with no maximum compatibility seems to have that resource (0x040C) also.

Comment: @MarkSatchell Your link does say this though: _"If maximize compatibility is unchecked then the merged/composite is not created and the layer data must be read to reproduce the final image."_ So apparently my assumption was correct, just not seeing it in real life here. Hmmm...